Question about a specific proof that every manifold has a countable basis of regular coordinate balls
In "Introduction to Topological Manifolds" by John M. Lee we have the following proposition:

Proposition 4.60. Every manifold has a countable basis of regular coordinate balls.

The proof Lee gives is as follows:

Proof. Let M be an n-manifold. Every point of M is contained in a Euclidean
neighborhood, and since M is second countable, a countable collection {$U_i : i \in \mathbb{N}$}
of such neighborhoods covers M by Theorem 2.50. For each of these open subsets
$U_i$, choose a homeomorphism $\phi_i$ from $U_i$ to an open subset $\phi(U_i) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. For each
$x \in \phi(U_i)$, the fact that $\phi(U_i)$ is open means that there is some positive number $r(x)$ such
that $B_{r(x)}(x) \subset \phi(U_i)$.
Now let $\mathcal{B}$ be the collection of all open subsets of M of the form $\phi^{-1}(B_r(x))$,
where $x \in \phi(U_i)$ is a point with rational coordinates and r is any positive rational
number strictly less than r(x). Then it follows from Lemma 4.59 that each such set
is a regular coordinate ball. Since there are only countably many such balls for each
$U_i$, the collection $\mathcal{B}$ is countable.
It remains only to check that the collection B is a basis for M , which we leave
as an exercise.

I was trying to prove that $\mathcal{B}$ is indeed a basis. However I had to make a sligth modification of Lee's proof to do so, I had to set $r(x)$ "as big as possible" (in other words, $r(x) = \sup \{r \in  \mathbb{R}, B_r(x) \subset \phi(U_i)\}$, it is defined since it is a non empty subset of the reals, and if it is unbounded, then I set $r(x) = +\infty$). I call this new collection, for which $r(x)$ is as big as possible, $\mathcal{B}'$.
In particular, this guarantees that if $x \in \mathbb{Q}^n$, and $B_r(x) \subset \phi(U_i)$ for some $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ I have no precise control over, then $\phi^{-1}(B_r(x)) \in \mathcal{B}'$ (unless we are in the special case where $r=r(x) \in \mathbb{Q}$, but I can also make this case work), even though it might not belong to $\mathcal{B}$.
Here is my attempt at showing that $\mathcal{B}'$ is a basis:
Let $U$ be a open set of M. Then $U = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} U \cap U_i$ so I can actually focus on each $U \cap U_i$ separately and show that they can be generated by $\mathcal{B}'$
Since $\phi(U \cap U_i)$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, I can express it as a union of open balls whose centers belong to $\mathbb{Q}^n$ and whose radii are rational numbers (the fact that those balls whose center have rational coordinates and rational radii form a basis of the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has been proven earlier in the book and can be used freely without justification).
Therefore, for each $x \in U \cap U_i$, $\phi(x) \in B_r(y) \subset \phi(U \cap U_i) \subset \phi(U_i)$ for some $r \in \mathbb{Q}^+$ and $y \in \mathbb{Q}^n$. Now since I chose $r(y)$ to be "as big as possible", I am guaranteed that $\phi^{-1}(B_r(y))$ is in the collection $\mathcal{B}'$ since $r < r(y)$ (in the special case where $r = r(y) \in \mathbb{Q}$, then I can consider $r' \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $d(\phi(x),y) <r'<r$ and then $x \in \phi^{-1}(B_{r'}(y))$ and $\phi^{-1}(B_{r'}(y)) \in \mathcal{B}'$ since $r' < r(y)$).
I do this for every $x \in U \cap U_i$, and  by taking the union of all those coordinate balls $\phi^{-1}(B_r(y))$ I can recover the whole set $U \cap U_i$.
As you can see, my current argument only works if I am guaranteed that $\phi^{-1}(B_r(y)) \in \mathcal{B}'$.
So here is my question (finally) : Is it possible to continue Lee's proof in the way he intended, that is by showing that $\mathcal{B}$ (not $\mathcal{B}'$) is a basis of M ?
In other words, that it is impossible to "pathologically select" the r(x)'s (for example by making them arbitrarily small for no reason as we get closer to a point $x_0$) such that the collection $\mathcal{B}$ defined is not a basis of M.
If no matter the choice of $r(x)$, $\mathcal{B}$ is always a basis, I am not asking for a full proof, just a confirmation that this is true and a hint that could help me see why.
If not, I would be thankful if you could give me a concrete example of a choice of $r(x)$'s such that $\mathcal{B}$ is not a basis of M.

Proposition 2.44 gives equivalent conditions for set $\mathcal{B}$ to be a basis. Have you tried proving  it this way?

From my understanding (I may be wrong), Proposition 2.44 says that if a set $\mathcal{B}$ satisfies some properties, then it is a basis for some topology. But here, the topology is already fixed (the manifold M is assumed to be equipped with a topology, I can't change it). And there is no reason to assume that the two topologies (the one induced by a set $\mathcal{B}$ and the one that comes with M) are necessarily the same.

Yes you are correct. I didn't read it carefully, and proving that it defines the same topology would most likely be more cumbersome

Although I think that if basis $\mathcal{B}$ is subset of original topology $\tau$, then it should generate the same topology $\tau$. Not 100% sure at the moment

Take $\mathbb{R}$ with discrete topology - it is obvious that basis for a standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is subset of discrete topology and yet it does not generate discrete topology. So my comments can be safely ignored. Sorry for spamming.

In general $\mathcal B$ as defined by Lee is no basis. Here is a counterexample:
Let $M = \mathbb R$. Then it suffices to take $U_1 = \mathbb R$ as a single Euclidean neighborhood and $\phi_1 = id$.
For each $x \in \phi_1(U) = \mathbb R$ we can choose $r(x) = \lvert x - \sqrt 2 \rvert$ if $x \ne \sqrt 2$ and $r(\sqrt 2) = 1$. Then $\sqrt 2$ is not contained in any $B_r(q)$ with $q \in \mathbb Q$ and $r \le r(x)$.
Remark.
To get a countable basis of regular coordinate balls it suffices to observe that the set $\mathcal E = \{B_r(x) \mid x \in \mathbb Q^n, r \in \mathbb Q^+ \}$ is a countable basis for $\mathbb R^n$ (which is easy to verify).
Then
$$\mathcal B = \{\phi_i^{-1}(E) \mid i \in \mathbb N, E \in \mathcal E \text{ such that } \overline E \subset \phi_i(U_i) \}$$
clearly does the job. Note that if $\overline{B_r(x)} \subset \phi_i(U_i)$, then also $B_{r'}(x) \subset \phi_i(U_i)$ for some $r'> r$. Since $\phi_i^{-1}(B_{r'}(x))$ is a coordinate ball, $\phi_i^{-1}(B_r(x))$ is a regular coordinate ball.

Lee became aware that his definition does not work. See https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/ITM/errata.pdf

I didn't see your answer before I posted mine, but I guess I was channeling your answer, because I gave essentially the same counterexample.

@Anthony You are right, I ignored the word "regular". See my update.

You're right, that was a mistake. I posted a correction a few years ago. (I recommend that you keep the link to my correction list handy while you're reading the book.) My correction was a little different from yours, but your idea works too.
Here's a counterexample of the sort you requested:
Let $M=\mathbb R$, with the single coordinate chart $(\mathbb R, \operatorname{Id})$. For each $x\in\mathbb Q$, choose $r(x) = |x-\pi|$.
Then the point $\pi$ is not in $B_{r}(x)$ for any rational $x$ and rational $r<r(x)$.

This answer is written by the author of the book. I'm adding a comment to note it, since this is currently only visible via the answerer's username, which might change or be disassociated in future.

Thank you for your answer and for having written this book Professor Lee. I am really enjoying reading your book and feel like I have already learned so much from it.
